# Low Pass Filter android

Tags: android, filter

I am trying to adapt a low pass filter from this site:
[Low Pass Filter](https://www.built.io/blog/2013/05/applying-low-pass-filter-to-android-sensors-readings/)

My problem is that I do not know what is the goal of below line:

```
int rotation = Compatibility.getRotation(this);
```

I have googled a lot in order to search information about this but without no luck. Anyone knows what it does?

See below piece of code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
    if (evt.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gravSensorVals = lowPass(evt.values.clone(), gravSensorVals);
    } else if (evt.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        magSensorVals = lowPass(evt.values.clone(), magSensorVals);
    }
    if (gravSensorVals != null && magSensorVals != null) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RTmp, I, gravSensorVals, magSensorVals);
        int rotation = Compatibility.getRotation(this);
        if (rotation == 1) {
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, Rot);
        } else {
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(RTmp, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, Rot);
        }
        SensorManager.getOrientation(Rot, results);
        UIARView.azimuth = (float)(((results[0]*180)/Math.PI)+180);
        UIARView.pitch = (float)(((results[1]*180/Math.PI))+90);
        UIARView.roll = (float)(((results[2]*180/Math.PI)));
        radarMarkerView.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From android documentation: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()), it will check the device orientation. So value of one is ROTATION_90. device rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise.

Comment: but I get compilation error on Compatibility key word... Is this an android class?

Comment: No, this is part of augmented reality class. In android you have to use view.getDisplay.getRotation(); instead.  https://github.com/Bhide/AugmentedRealityView/blob/master/ARView/src/com/raw/utils/Compatibility.java

Comment: ok, I suppose that the piece of code int rotation=Compatibility.getRotation(this), and the below conditional is not nedeed for me as I only want to filter accelerometer and magnetic fields values. By applying lowPass function is enough, right?

Comment: Also I think that in my case that I only want to filter noiser, it is not necessary to apply the remapCoordinateSystem on sensormanger, right?